# Does Hawking radiation violate baryon number conservation?

Tags: antimatter, hawking-radiation, baryons

Throw two baryons into a black hole ([baryon number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number) +2), receive [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) out. [Convert the resulting energy into one baryon and one anti-baryon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production) (baryon number 0).

[Baryon number conservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baryon_number#Conservation) seems to disallow such a thing.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please see my comments on this one: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/483933/does-the-life-of-a-black-hole-violate-baryon-number-conservation/483943#483943

Comment: I think you are confusing two different frames of reference and misunderstanding what Hawking radiation is about.

If two or any number of baryons go through the horizon, the baryon conservation number of the black hole will go up by the number of baryons entered,awking radiation happens at the horizon, i.e the point of no return from the black hole. The zero baryon number is counting what is happening to the radiation. If a loop is formed at the horizon, and one of the pair (baryon -antibarion) will fall into the black hole,

Comment: either increasing by one or decreasing by one the baryon number of the black hole .. One of the pair falls into the sink, one goes free taking energy from the fields of the black hole at the horizon.

Comment: @annav the [no hair theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-hair_theorem) suggests that black holes have no baryon number.

Comment: @Scott one can think of baryon number below the horizon. Every thing is a model. I just wanted to clear for you that conservation of baryon number is separate: black hole versus pair production.  .

Comment: that the classical solution does not conserve baryon numbers falling into the black hole  is different than our question. The pair production at the horizon happens in an independent frame than the black hole absorption (or not)  of quantum numbers. for the radiation see my answer here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/186682/hawking-radiation-and-curvature  and here and here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/451618/why-does-hawking-radiation-outside-the-schwarzschild-radius-decrease-a-black-hol

Comment: "that the classical solution does not conserve baryon numbers falling into the black hole."  That, I think, is precisely my question.